# Issue with making jQuery Modal pop-up work with ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui-dialog

I created a MVC 5 application using the template from VS 2013.

This does not come with jQuery UI so I added 1.11.1 version using PM.
No reason for that version but found a tutorial on YouTube using that.

The Contents folder looks like this:

[image: Contents Folder]

The Scripts folder looks like this:

[image: Scripts folder]

I want to work with the modal pop-up that jQuery UI offers so just to try out modified _Layout.cshtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    <link href="~/Content/themes/base/dialog.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui.min-1.11.1.js"></script>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#dialog-modal").dialog({
                width: 400,
                height: 200,
                modal: true
            });
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                @Html.ActionLink("Application name", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
        </footer>
    </div>


    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

This is the modal div in Index.cshtml:

```
<div id="dialog-modal" title="Schedule Preview" style="display:none">
    <p>This is empty preview</p>
</div>
```

The modal does pop-up when the site loads but it's messed up beyond description. So here is a screenshot with the pop-up marked in red.

[image: Invisible pop-up]

Can someone please guide me on what's going on here and how to fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you should comment out the MVC default stylesheets possibly and any extra javascript and then gradually reintroduce things. Start with a blank view with no styles and confirm whether you dialogue actually works.

Comment: You need to load more that just dialog.css, as that just contains the rules for the modal.

Answer (score 0):

Using the version of jQuery that uses separate JS/CSS files for the various components, you need to load more that just `dialog.css`. From a custom build, toggling only the dialog, it looks like you need:

- core.css
- draggable.css
- resizable.css
- button.css
- dialog.css
- theme.css

If you also only want to load the individual JavaScript files, you need:

- core.js
- widget.js
- mouse.js
- position.js
- draggable.js
- resizable.js
- button.js
- dialog.js

If you'd rather simplify this, you can just load `all.css` (and possibly `theme.css`), though you'll run into conflicts with Bootstrap, if you're using it.

Comment: I included all.css and now the modal comes up with the 'x' missing at the upper right. Any clues?

Comment: Hard to say. I would suspect a conflict with the Bootstrap styles; jQuery UI and Bootstrap do not normally mesh very well in the same project.

Comment: @Codehelp You may want to consider using the Bootstrap modal plugin rather than trying to get jQuery UI to work, if you plan on using Bootstrap. There's also [Bootbox](http://bootboxjs.com), if you want something a little simpler.